# How to Use a Uri to Launch a Task

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have recently discovered one of the new additions to WP8, URI schemes that can be used to launch built-in apps. I was wondering how exactly to use these. For example, in a click event simply using

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-location:"));
```

does not work. The error window says `Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.` How do I do this? I do not have experience with the await operator yet.

Comment: Tempted for -1... Please add explanation of what is unclear in MSDN article about [LaunchUriAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh701480.aspx): `var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);` .

Comment: New to what/how Async method works. I think I got it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put an await operator on your method like this

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-location:"));
```

and put an async operator on your base method or event like this

```
//example
private async void OnNavigatedTo()
{

}
```

Its easy, Hope it helps

Comment: Ha yes. Just figured it out and then checked back here to answer. So can you explain the benefit of this. The event occurs in a background thread?

Comment: async await helps increasing the compilation productivity. Its a new feature added in wp8/win8. http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Asynchronous_Programming_For_Windows_Phone_8 this links gives a fantastic explanation of the problem.